# Using Ionic, when running ngIf, a drop down menu should appear, and it doesnt

Tags: ionic-framework

Good evening beautiful community, 
I'm having problems developing an app on Ionic. I started programming it on July, stopped on November, and when I tried to run it again this February, the ngIf didn't display correctly. 
In addition to this, when I run the command Ionic serve, the browser runs the app correctly, on the first try. On the second, it doesn't display what I said earlier. When I run the command Ionic Cordoba run browser, or when I try to run the .apk in my phone, it displays a lot of errors.
The ngIf code is as follows:

```
  <div *ngIf="option==1">
<ion-item lines="full">
  <ion-label position="floating">text 1</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="something 1"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item lines="full">
  <ion-label position="floating">text 2</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="something 2"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

The text 1/2, something 1/2, and option==1 are something different in the code.

this is the Ionic im using:

- Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.6
- (C:\Users[myname]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)    Ionic
- Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
- @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3    @angular-devkit/schematics
  : 8.1.3    @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
- @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

What should I do? Any help will be appreciated. 
I Think there might be something wrong on the Ionic side of this, because the code used to work perfectly.  Maybe a new update messed things up? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code posted does not contain the closing div tag

Comment: What is the value of `option` say when the `if` isn't displaying as you expected it to?

Comment: the  </div> wasnt tabbed correctly when I made the question, so it doesnt show, but its there. It's not that.

Comment: It's an Item. When you click it, a menu drops down and shows you text spaces, to write in. If it isnt clicked on, or it's clicked off, it should not display said menu.